# Select id from one table and its value from another table to search

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, sql-like

I have two tables named `company` and `customers`.

In `company` table there are 3 fields `ID`, `Company`, and `Type` as:

```
ID    Company    Type
1     ABC        Running

2     XYZ        Current
```

Now again in `customers` table I submitted the value of company and customers, but here the value of company is submitted as an `ID` as:

```
Company     Customer Name
1              monty

2             sandeep
```

now I want to search the company name in customer table but when i put company name in search box its showing nothing because the value of company name is in ID form in customer tabe.how can i achieve it.

Here is my query for search:

```
$sql = "Select * from customers where name like '%$term%' or location like '%$term%' or company like '%$term%'";
```

Comment: Monty, you should take a look at JOINS in SQL. They very important and surely you are gonna use them all the time. You can get started by this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @medina: sure and thnks for this precious advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)ing the two tables:

```
Select * 
from customers AS cust
INNER JOIN companies AS comp ON cust.Company = comp.Id
where comp.location like '%$term%' 
   or comp.company like '%$term%'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try this

SELECT co.*, cu.* FROM company as co, customers as cu where co.company_id = cu.company_id and co.company_name = '%$term%';
```